# Split XML report in SQL

Tags: sql, xml

I have below SQL stored procedure which generates a report and sends to me via email.
However it sends all the various rows as one big chunk report.
Rather I would want it to split each error
Any idea how I can split the below query to have individual XML reports generated.

```
DECLARE @Report XML
BEGIN
    
    UPDATE [Orders].dbo.PurOrd
    SET [Status] = 'Failed', Reason = '<e id="0" message="failed test order" />'
    WHERE [Status] = 'InProcess' 
    SET @Report = (
        SELECT 
            
            p.Name as "@Name",
            p.Customer "@Customer",
            CASE p.Name
                WHEN 'Default' THEN convert(xml,p.RejectedReason)
                ELSE convert(xml,f.RejectedReason)
            END AS "RejectedReason",
            (
                SELECT u.first_name as "@FirstName",
                u.last_name as "@LastName",
                FROM [Users].dbo.Users u
                WHERE u.user_id = u.user_id
                for xml PATH('Users'), type
            ),
            (
                SELECT
                li.Product as "@PId",
                li.Quantity as "@Quantity",
                li.SalePrice as "@Price",
                FROM [Cart].dbo.LineItems li
                WHERE li.OrderFormId = f.OrderFormId
                ORDER BY li.ItemNumber
                for xml PATH('LineItem'), type
            )
        FROM [Orders].dbo.OrForms f
            JOIN [Orders].dbo.PurOrd p on f.GroupId = p.GroupId
        WHERE 
            (p.Status = 'OrderRejected' AND p.ReportStatus IS NULL)
        FOR XML PATH('test'), TYPE
    )
SELECT @Report FOR XML PATH('Report')
```

Current Output:

```
<Report>
<PurchaseOrder OrderId="Order 1" Name="name1" Seller="abc">
    <Reason>
      <errors>
        <e id="0" message="failed test ord" />
      </errors>
    </Reason>
    <Users FirstName="abc" LastName="xyz"/>
    <LineItem ProductId="Clothes1" Quantity="1.0000" SalePrice="100rs"/>
</PurchaseOrder>
<PurchaseOrder OrderId="Order 2" Name="name 2" Seller="abc">
    <Reason>
      <errors>
        <e id="0" message="failed test ord" />
      </errors>
    </Reason>
    <Users FirstName="abc" LastName="xyz"/>
    <LineItem ProductId="Clothes1" Quantity="1.0000" SalePrice="100rs"/>
  </PurchaseOrder>
</Report>
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
<Report>
<PurchaseOrder OrderId="Order 1" Name="name1" Seller="abc">
    <Reason>
      <errors>
        <e id="0" message="failed test ord" />
      </errors>
    </Reason>
    <Users FirstName="abc" LastName="xyz"/>
    <LineItem ProductId="Clothes1" Quantity="1.0000" SalePrice="100rs"/>
</PurchaseOrder>
</Report>
<Report>
<PurchaseOrder OrderId="Order 2" Name="name 2" Seller="abc">
    <Reason>
      <errors>
        <e id="0" message="failed test ord" />
      </errors>
    </Reason>
    <Users FirstName="abc" LastName="xyz"/>
    <LineItem ProductId="Clothes1" Quantity="1.0000" SalePrice="100rs"/>
  </PurchaseOrder>
</Report>
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Current Output  does't match the query.

Comment: I have just edited my query and output tag names. But that's the query structure with some dummy data.

Comment: @ish_dev, where are ##1-4? You are asking forum to create your desired XML out of the thin air?

Answer (score 0):

One way to get

```
<Report>
   <PurchaseOrder ... >
     ...
   </PurchaseOrder>
</Report>
<Report>
   <PurchaseOrder ...>
    ...
   </PurchaseOrder>
</Report>
```

structure is to wrap your select list into CROSS APLLY. Kind of

```
    SELECT t.PurchaseOrder
    FROM [Orders].dbo.OrForms f
    JOIN [Orders].dbo.PurOrd p on f.GroupId = p.GroupId
    CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT
        -- original select list copy
        p.Name as "@Name",
        p.Customer "@Customer",
        CASE p.Name
            WHEN 'Default' THEN convert(xml,p.RejectedReason)
            ELSE convert(xml,f.RejectedReason)
        END AS "RejectedReason",
        (
            SELECT u.first_name as "@FirstName",
            u.last_name as "@LastName",
            FROM [Users].dbo.Users u
            WHERE u.user_id = u.user_id
            for xml PATH('Users'), type
        ),
        (
            SELECT
            li.Product as "@PId",
            li.Quantity as "@Quantity",
            li.SalePrice as "@Price",
            FROM [Cart].dbo.LineItems li
            WHERE li.OrderFormId = f.OrderFormId
            ORDER BY li.ItemNumber
            for xml PATH('LineItem'), type
        )
        -- original select list copy END          
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ) t(PurchaseOrder)
    WHERE 
        (p.Status = 'OrderRejected' AND p.ReportStatus IS NULL)
    FOR XML PATH('Report'), TYPE;
```

Comment: Serg, how can  I run and test your proposed solution? Additionally, as you mentioned in your earlier comments: "Current Output does't match the query."

Comment: You need some test data for that and also to correct original select list syntax  `, FROM` definitly will not compile.

Comment: My entire point that you are falling into  a trap of the OP.

Comment: Hope @ish_dev has correct original select list and test data.

Comment: @serg It has an update list and not select. CROSS APPLY isn't helping.

Comment: Your update statement is ok. Change only SELECT ..  in `SET @Report = (..)`.  And finally just `SELECT @Report;`

Comment: I do get an error on t.....'t' has more columns than were specified in the column list.